# Can I test websockets with Jersey Test Framework?

Tags: websocket, jersey, jersey-test-framework

I have a Restful web service that I want to test. For this I use the Jersey Test Framework. In addition to the JAX-RS resources are also used websockets, which should also be tested. But when I tried to test websocket endpoint using Tyrus client I got 404 instead of the 101 code.

```
org.glassfish.tyrus.core.HandshakeException: Response code was not 101: 404.
```

In a case when I build the war file - websocket endpoint works fine and everything works as expected.
Can I test websockets with Jersey Test Framework?

---

Jersey 1.18